# Does Query Parameter Usage in Apollo Client Affect Performance?

Tags: apollo-client, next-router

Description Link : https://2a7.notion.site/Performance-Report-880f12da5d054c27b2644ef887790d7f?pvs=4

I've been analyzing the performance of an application using Apollo Client for GraphQL queries and noticed some significant changes in response times. I followed a systematic approach to measure the performance, alternating between tests and using Incognito Mode with cleared cache and hard refresh for each measurement.

Before making any improvements, I used router.push for navigation, which resulted in response times of 7.68 seconds, 5.85 seconds, and 6.38 seconds respectively. After implementing improvements by using useContext, the response times were reduced to 4.68 seconds, 4.5 seconds, and 5.16 seconds.

This change led to an average improvement of 1.85 seconds. In particular, the time from the loading page to the Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) completion showed a 2-second difference, dropping from 2.5 seconds to just 0.5 seconds post-improvement.

Further analysis indicated that the query calls were the primary cause of delay, showing a difference of 1.97 seconds. The query calls took 2 seconds before improvements and just 300 milliseconds after.

However, repeated measurements and Network tab checks revealed inconsistencies in query response times, even though the same queries were called. Before the improvement, query response times were around 2.24 seconds, while after the improvement, they dropped to 0.32 seconds.

Could the use of query parameters in Apollo Client be contributing to this slowdown? I'm curious if there's a known correlation between query parameter usage in Apollo Client and these observed performance variations.

[image: Using router params state]
[image: Using useContext state]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by query parameters, as the screenshots don't indicate the use of url query parameters before or after.

What I see is that you're using the `BatchHttpLink` though. While generally that minimizes the number of requests, it also means that on the server a response is only sent after all batched requests have fully been processed - if one of these queries is slow, it will slow all the others down. It might be worth a try with a normal HttpLink for initial page load.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

To clarify, the initial URL used was https://localhost:3000?productId=129382190381240 using next router params, and after optimization, it was changed to https://localhost:3000, with client-side management using React's useContext. This change led to a 2-second difference in LCP. We suspect this difference may be due to the speed of Apollo Client query calls, but the exact reason is unclear, hence my inquiry.

Comment: The problem was specifically about fetching the selected value either through router parameters or by utilizing useContext as a global variable.

Upon inspecting the Performance tab in developer tools, I observed a 2-second discrepancy. The only notable difference in the two scenarios was the execution time of the same Apollo Client queries.

I'm unsure why such a significant time difference arises merely from the way selected is obtained, especially since the Apollo Client queries, which were the common element in both cases, showed a variance in execution time.

Comment: @chloepark I would guess that before you had SSR in place, which did the data fetching on the server, and now you essentially disabled SSR and moved the queries to a point in time after the first contentful paint. So now you're measuring a faster time until something is on the screen, but the full page might take the same time as before.